# Possible to get all intellisense on .js files?

Tags: visual-studio-code

This is specific question about .js files. Not .ts files. With ts files i'm able to get it all working properly.

I made all the setup options for js files and it still doesn't work, if at all possible:

jsconfig.json in project root:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true // false doesn't change anything
  },
   "files": [
    "typings/index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

I also installed typings for node, and all express standard typings.

Yet, on my app.js file:

```
import * as express from "foo"
var app = exfprdess();
```

doesn't trigger any underlined error. How to get proper behavior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio Code, by default, doesn't lint your code (meaning it doesn't check for errors).

Visual Studio Code *can*, however, lint your code, you'll just have to configure something like [ESLint or JSLint](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_javascript-linters-eslint-jshint).

Comment: eslint is good, but it won't tell when you have a mistyped error on, let's say, an express method name.

Comment: @RobertBrax Yes, however using the `no-undef` option, in most cases, should cause ESLint to complain whenever you mistype a variable/function's name.